# At-sign in haml class names

Tags: haml

I'm trying to make a webpage with UIkit (the front-end framework, not the iOS framework).

From v3, UIkit uses at-signs in its responsive class names (`.uk-text-left@s` affects small devices and up, `.uk-text-left@l` large devices and up...).

Using those classes directly causes haml to complain:

> Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %div
>   and nested within it. (Haml::SyntaxError)

Or, if the html element doesn't contain any other elements, to produce a wrong output, with the @ in the html content:

```
<div class="uk-text-left">@s hello</div>
```

Using `%div{ :class => "uk-text-left@s" }` works fine, but this kind of frameworks rely so heavily on those classes that it makes a huge difference compared to just typing `.uk-text-left@s`.

Is there any other way to make haml accept the at-sign as part of the class name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to use the long form methods for attributes.

Instead of the shorthand method

```
%h1.awesome-sauce
```

You'll need to do this

```
%h1{class: "@awesome-sauce"}
```

The shorthand is just syntactic sugar. You could always write a helper or decorator to handle the name generation if there is an obvious pattern.

Comment: I was afraid so :( Thanks. New to haml, I'll see if I can manage to understand helpers and decorators.

Comment: helpers and decorates are just an object oriented programming design pattern to handle times like these in the view. Good luck!